# psql: error: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "blog" in PostgreSQL for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Im trying to create a user for PostgreSQL in order to connect a database created with this new user to a Django project. So I created a new user called "blog" with this SQL command:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER blog WITH PASSWORD '********';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE blog WITH OWNER 'blog' ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

When I try to access Postgres with the user ‘blog’ it says:

```
~$ sudo -u blog psql blog
sudo: unknown user: blog
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I cannot access with:

```
~$ psql blog blog
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "blog"
```

I don't understand why, if I just created the user “blog”. It is even visible on my pgAdmin4 panel.

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and psql (13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1.pgdg20.04+1))

Comment: To use the simple form of peer authentication, you need an OS user whose name matches the database user.  Note that the unknown user error is coming from sudo, not from psql.  If you want to use password authentication, then you need to change your pg_hba.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

A database user is something else than an operating system user.

You tried `sudo -u blog` so that you are able to use "peer" authentication, but that operating system use does not exist.

Your options:

- choose a different authentication method like "trust" or password authentication
- create the operating system user `blog`
- add a [mapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-username-maps.html) that allows a different operating system user to connect as `blog` with "peer" authentication